# Visual Studio Express 2013 CSS Intellisense not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have VS Express 2013 installed with update 1. In a brand new Web Forms project, CSS intellisense doesn't work for anything other than styles defined within the page. The Bootstrap styles are showing when I run the page so I know the styles are  bundled properly. When I create a new MVC project, the CSS Intellisense works properly. Any ideas why Intellisense doesn't pick up Bootstrap or anything else for that matter in Web Forms? Are there settings settings I can change?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I tried resetting VS settings, reinstalling Bootstrap etc. Which didn't work. I also tried using the MVC Bundeling <%:Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %> that didn't work...

In the end I used this hack... I added the below to the master page.

Under this:  webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />

```
**<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />**
```

Works fine, just remember to remove them on release, or when someone finds a better fix.

Comment: This worked for me. I also notice that Ctrl-KS does not identify Bootstrap in Web Forms either, even with this fix.

Answer (score 2):

I use the #if DEBUG directive.  The web.config and web.release.config controls the rest (debug=true|false). I always get intellisense when coding and bundled css when publishing.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <% #if DEBUG %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css"  />
    <% #else %>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <% #endif %>
</head>
```

Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```